# Android Studio widgets don't appear in app

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3xZe.png)I have added two sliders and two textviews to the design tab in activity_main.xml and they don't seem to be appearing when I run the app. 
I am not getting any errors, so I am confused as to what might be causing the widgets to not appear in the app when it is run. Has anyone else experienced it? If so, how was this problem solved? 
Thanks in advance.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.umeer.drawindapp1.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/clear"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.014" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/width"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/opacity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.996" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[screenshot of the app and design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3xZe.png)

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyDraw d = new MyDraw(this);
        setContentView(d);

        Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
```

Mydraw is the view I am using but the program doesn't let me use Button b = findViewByID(d.id.button)

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Floern I have added the code from the xml file to the question

Comment: Please insert the full content of the xml file. There should be a FrameLayout / RelativeLayout / ConstraintLayout (which you seem to use) or some similar container around your views.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann The code snippets have been updated

Comment: Does your MyDraw class have any reference to the XML layout? You do create the activity, but you don't use the XML layout in this code (unless the MyDraw class accesses it).